# PostgreSQL, динамический запрос в триггерной функции

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица **geo**, от нее наследуется 100 таблиц **geo_1**, **geo_2**, ..., **geo_100**.
Мне нужно при запросе

```
   INSERT INTO geo VALUES(50, 100)
```

редиректить в geo_50,

```
   INSERT INTO geo VALUES(25, 100)
```

редиректить в geo_25,

Написал вот такую функцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.geo_ins()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
            DECLARE
              partition_name varchar := 'geo_' || new.object_id;
            begin
              EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO geo_' || new.object_id || ' SELECT new.*';
              return null;
            end;
            $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Она дергается вот таким триггером:

```
CREATE TRIGGER geo_partition_ins
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON public.geo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.geo_ins();
```

Но эта функция не работает, при попытке заинсертить пишет:

```
ОШИБКА:  таблица "new" отсутствует в предложении FROM
LINE 1: INSERT INTO geo_100 SELECT new.*
                                   ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO geo_100 SELECT new.*
CONTEXT:  функция PL/pgSQL geo_ins(), строка 5, оператор EXECUTE

********** Error **********

ОШИБКА: таблица "new" отсутствует в предложении FROM
SQL state: 42P01
Context: функция PL/pgSQL geo_ins(), строка 5, оператор EXECUTE
```

что мне нужно поправить?

Comment: Ну да, внутри execute new не доступна, у него своя область видимости. Что поправить - изменить структуру БД заменив 100 таблиц на одну

Comment: Это секции, я специально разбил таблицу на несколько, потому что она будет огромной. Есть ли еще какой-нибудь вариант?

Comment: Для понимания работы - https://habrahabr.ru/post/273933/ . Но не надо делать закат солнца вручную, используйте расширение pg_partman.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ответ в этой статье.

Comment: В итоге все делается вот так:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.geo_ins() RETURNS trigger AS
            $BODY$
            DECLARE
                v_partition_name text;
            BEGIN
                v_partition_name := format('geo_%s', NEW.object_id);
                execute 'INSERT INTO ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES ( ($1).* )' USING NEW;
                return NULL;
            END;
            $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;